# Is mongodb aggrerate $match option dynamic?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Say,I want to add a new field named "di5km" to a large mongodb collection,but the calculation of the field value is slow. So I want to start more process and use the $exists as the filter to skip the records that already have "di5km" field, the question is if the item selected by the aggrarate was dynamic?  my code is as follows:

```
db["point"].aggregate([{
 $match:{
   "di5km":{$exists:false}
 }
}],{allowDiskUse: true}).foreach(){

// calculate field value
// set new field 
}
```

will one process know a record has already been modified by another one so skip it?

Comment: sadly the answer is NO